# Threejs can't show scene in specific div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, three.js

I am trying to show a geometry in a specific `<div>`, say my main canvas, to later drag from `<li>` items within a `<div>` at the top of the page.
Here is my HTML

```
<body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <div class="drag-container">
        <ul>
            <li class="drag-item"></li>
            <li class="drag-item"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="main" id="canvas">
    </div>
</body>
```

In my index.js, I tried all of the following to find the div and set it as my canvas, but I had no success:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
```

and

```
const canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
```

and

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("main");
```

I wanted to add the rendered scene to the div by `canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);`.
Needless to say, adding the rendered scene to `document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)` in a simple page with no  `<div>`s works.
I also tried:

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(
    {
        alpha: true,
        antialias: true,
        canvas: canvas
    });
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to add a canvas to the div and then add the canvas to the renderer later on?

Comment: Working on a different copy (in Windows), I realized that there was a different problem and I found a solution: referencing the build mode of three.js, hence `import * as THREE from "./three.module.js"`;
then the `getElementById()` option worked. However, now there is a different problem: I don't have access to all sub-modules of THREE, e.g., I can't make a reference to `{ OrbitControls }` which is in the `"three/examples/jsm/controls/"` folder. There's possibly a trivial solution to this problem (I guess it's a dependency problem), but I don't know it yet.